# Python Pandas – How to supress PerformanceWarning?

Tags: python, pandas, suppress-warnings

How I can supress a PerformanceWarning in pandas?

I've already tried `warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=PerformanceWarning)`, but it gives me a `NameError: name 'PerformanceWarning' is not defined`

Comment: Can you try putting `warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=PerformanceWarning)` before `import pandas`?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

PerformanceWarning is not a built-in warning class so you can't call it directly in *category* argument. You can try the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import warnings

warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=pd.errors.PerformanceWarning)
```

I have no idea how to reproduce the PerformanceWarning but i tested a similar approach to the "*SettingWithCopyWarning*" pandas warning and it worked. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you. It worked! I have a PerformanceWarning with a pd.DateOffset() action.