# Breaking down year to monthly data with custom function

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, resampling

I'm trying to break down yearly subscriptions to monthly subscriptions by fee.

Example dataset-

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Customer_ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'Plan' : ['Yearly', 'Monthly', 'Monthly', 'Yearly', 'Yearly'],
    'Join_Date': ['1/10/2020', '1/15/2020', '2/21/2020', '2/21/2020', '3/09/2020'],
    'Fee' : [120, 12, 18, 86, 144]
})

df['Join_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Join_Date'])

df
```

Here, customer 1 has a yearly subscription fee of $120 between January 2020 and January 2021. I want my data frame to breakdown the fee between 2020-01 and 2020-12 to $10 ($120/12 months) each by displaying each month of that year with the monthly fee ($10).

I tried a bunch of resampling methods, but it didn't work. One example-

```
def atom(row):
    if df.Plan=='Yearly':
        return (df.Fee/12)

df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Join_Date', freq='1M')).apply(atom)
```

Expected output for first customer-

[image]

Is there another method?

Comment: Should your final dataframe have a row for each month? Can you add your desired result to the question?

Comment: can you not simply do `df.loc[df['Plan'] == 'Yearly'],'new_col'] = df.Fee/12`

Comment: @JoeFerndz No, that doesn't output each month between date X and date Y with the per month value. I'm trying to display each month between Jan 2020 to Jan 2021 with $10 in the same dataframe.

Comment: Can you please post the desired output so we can know what you are looking for please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First expand the yearly records by `np.repeat()`. Then perform the following action selectively on `df1["Plan"] == "Yearly"`:

- Monthly fee can be computed directly.
- Increments to months can be obtained using `groupby-cumcount` and mapped onto [`pd.DateOffset(months=)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46741423). Such method receives a `PerformanceWarning`, which can be suppressed [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51522841/3218693) (omitted in the code).

### Code

```
# expand the Yearly records
df1 = df.loc[np.repeat(df.index, df["Plan"].map({"Yearly": 12, "Monthly":1}))]

# compute monthly fee and join date 
df1.loc[df1["Plan"] == "Yearly", "Fee"] /= 12
df1.loc[df1["Plan"] == "Yearly", "Join_Date"] += \
    df1.groupby(["Customer_ID", "Plan"]).cumcount()\
       .loc[df1["Plan"] == "Yearly"]\
       .map(lambda i: pd.DateOffset(months=i))
```

### Result

```
print(df1)
   Customer_ID     Plan  Join_Date        Fee
0            1   Yearly 2020-01-10  10.000000
0            1   Yearly 2020-02-10  10.000000
0            1   Yearly 2020-03-10  10.000000
0            1   Yearly 2020-04-10  10.000000
0            1   Yearly 2020-05-10  10.000000
0            1   Yearly 2020-06-10  10.000000
0            1   Yearly 2020-07-10  10.000000
0            1   Yearly 2020-08-10  10.000000
0            1   Yearly 2020-09-10  10.000000
0            1   Yearly 2020-10-10  10.000000
0            1   Yearly 2020-11-10  10.000000
0            1   Yearly 2020-12-10  10.000000
1            2  Monthly 2020-01-15  12.000000
2            3  Monthly 2020-02-21  18.000000
3            4   Yearly 2020-02-21   7.166667
3            4   Yearly 2020-03-21   7.166667
3            4   Yearly 2020-04-21   7.166667
3            4   Yearly 2020-05-21   7.166667
3            4   Yearly 2020-06-21   7.166667
3            4   Yearly 2020-07-21   7.166667
3            4   Yearly 2020-08-21   7.166667
3            4   Yearly 2020-09-21   7.166667
3            4   Yearly 2020-10-21   7.166667
3            4   Yearly 2020-11-21   7.166667
3            4   Yearly 2020-12-21   7.166667
3            4   Yearly 2021-01-21   7.166667
4            5   Yearly 2020-03-09  12.000000
4            5   Yearly 2020-04-09  12.000000
4            5   Yearly 2020-05-09  12.000000
4            5   Yearly 2020-06-09  12.000000
4            5   Yearly 2020-07-09  12.000000
4            5   Yearly 2020-08-09  12.000000
4            5   Yearly 2020-09-09  12.000000
4            5   Yearly 2020-10-09  12.000000
4            5   Yearly 2020-11-09  12.000000
4            5   Yearly 2020-12-09  12.000000
4            5   Yearly 2021-01-09  12.000000
4            5   Yearly 2021-02-09  12.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Cutomer_ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'Plan' : ['Yearly', 'Monthly', 'Monthly', 'Yearly', 'Yearly'],
    'Join_Date': ['1/10/2020', '1/15/2020', '2/21/2020', '2/21/2020', '3/09/2020'],
    'Fee' : [120, 12, 18, 86, 144]
})

df['Join_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Join_Date'])

df['Monthly_Fee'] = df['Fee']
df.loc[df['Plan'] == 'Yearly','Monthly_Fee'] = (df.Fee/12).round(2)

print (df)
```

Output of this will be:

```
   Cutomer_ID     Plan  Join_Date  Fee  Monthly_Fee
0           1   Yearly 2020-01-10  120        10.00
1           2  Monthly 2020-01-15   12        12.00
2           3  Monthly 2020-02-21   18        18.00
3           4   Yearly 2020-02-21   86         7.17
4           5   Yearly 2020-03-09  144        12.00
```